# Tastypie unable to post with non-id primary key

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using django-tastypie to expose a django model. I'm having some problems posting to this resource however. It seems that tastypie doesn't like that I'm using another field for my primary key besides the 'id' field.

Here is the error I'm seeing:

```
"error_message": "Reverse for 'api_dispatch_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': u'VMware-42 30 21 91 31 77 1b 8a-75 c1 4f ab 70 d9 99 a6', 'api_name': 'v1', 'resource_name': 'system'}' not found.",
```

My model:

```
class System(models.Model):
    selinux = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    serialnumber = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    signer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tsm_pvu = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My resource:

```
class SystemResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
            queryset = System.objects.all()
            authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
            authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
            resource_name = 'system'
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem.  It turned out that the cause was not that the primary key was a non-ID field, but rather that the primary key included non-alphanumeric characters (e.g. spaces).  It seems as though that might be the case in your example too.

I found [this patch](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/273/files) which has not yet been merged with trunk, and which solved the problem for me.  The lines which need to be patched in tastypie 0.9.11 are lines 283-284 of (of the method base_urls) in file tastypie/resources.py.  Hope that helps.